# Counting result lines in pig latin

Tags: apache-pig

I'm trying to run simple word counter in pig latin as follows:

```
lines = LOAD 'SOME_FILES' using PigStorage('#') as (line:chararray);
word = FILTER lines BY (line matches '.*SOME_VALUE.*');
```

I want to count how many `SOME_VALUE`s found searching `SOME_FILES`, so the expected output should be something like:

```
(SOME_VALUE,xxxx)
```

Where `xxxx`, is the total number of `SOME_VALUE` found.

How can I search for multiple values and print each one as above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is split each line into a bag of tokens, then `FLATTEN` it.  Then you can do a `GROUP` on the words to pull all occurrences of each word into it's own line.  Once you do a `COUNT` of the resulting bag you'll have the total count for all words in the document.

This will look something like:

```
B = FOREACH lines GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) ;
C = GROUP B BY $0 ;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE group AS word, COUNT(B) AS count ;
```

If you aren't sure what each step is doing, then you can use `DESCRIBE` and `DUMP` to help visualize what is happening.

---

**Update:** If you want to filter the results to contain only the couple of strings you want you can do:

```
E = FILTER D BY (word == 'foo') OR 
                (word == 'bar') OR 
                (word == 'etc') ;

-- Another way...
E = FILTER D BY (word matches 'foo|bar|etc') ;
```

However, you can also do this between `B` and `C` so you don't do any `COUNT`s you don't need to.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you only want to see a certain set of strings in the output?